# Increasing the height of text without increasing its width also

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the height of my text in html, without increasing its width proportionally. When I increase the `font-size`, the increase is both in the horizontal as well as vertical direction.

---

You may think of it like stretching the height of the text, with its width constant. Can I do that using CSS?

Comment: Shoulnt you be searching for a different font instead? On most occasions stretching a font in any direction seriously messes up the font. Maybe you would be better off using a more compressed font instead of compressing a wider font yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scale transform property from CSS3:

```
.condensed {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 2);
       -moz-transform: scale(1, 2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1, 2);
         -o-transform: scale(1, 2);
            transform: scale(1, 2);
}​
```

Because it takes two values, you can scale the height and width of the letters.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/8bT8q/

As you can see, if you switch the values, the letters are stretched the other way.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/8bT8q/1/

Be aware that this is a CSS3 property and won't be supported by all browsers (mostly IE<9).

Also take in to account that the element will effectively keep its width as i the text were not scaled, so if you have some layout quirks this might be the reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/8bT8q/2/

Here I set the bg color of the scaled `<h1>` to show the effect.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably do it for you.

```
.higher {
    transform:scale(1,2);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1,2);
    -moz-transform:scale(1,2);
    -ms-transform:scale(1,2);
    -o-transform:scale(1,2);
}
```

Comment: It increases the size alright, but the width also increases somewhat giving it an akward look !!

Comment: Which browser do you use? My Chrome(v.20) doesn't change the width at all.

Comment: @MarcusJohansson Nice one. I created a demo using your styles, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/x4NeX/